# NestJS continuous deployment cycle documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, nestjs

I'm looking to use NestJS on my next project, but I am slightly put off by the lack of documentation regarding deployment practices and continuous deployment cycles. Ideally I would like to use something like cloud compute to automatically compile my project and deploy it as updates are pushed to a release branch. Anyone have advice regarding that?

Answer (score 2):

It is a very broad question, as there are many ways to implement CI, deployment pipeline, or deployment strategies.
I would suggest you to take a look to developer tools in AWS such as CodePipeline, for pipeline creation and CodeBuild/Jenkins as building services. Take a look at docker container, and look for deployment services like Elastic Beanstalk for single/multicontainer container, ECS, or just CodeDeploy.
I would also suggest you to take a look to [AWS Blue/Green deployments white paper](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Blue_Green_Deployments.pdf), as it also review the different deployment strategies.

Comment: Thanks for your response it’s great! I realise it’s a bit general as I am a bit new to it all I am trying to play with a few things. I used codepipline last time to deploy new front end to S3 bucket every time I updated my github repository. I thought this was a great method but couldn’t find much information for achieving this with backend code and what to host it on since we can’t use S3 for that.

Comment: I suggest you look into CI/CD for Express and/or Fastify. As Simon says :), it depends on the target deployment environment